# takes from 3 to 5 positional arguments but 6 were given?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program is supposed to draw a chessboard using user input. The drawing has to occur with the call of draw(). I am getting an error:

```
line 18, in main
 chessboard = Chessboard(tr, startX, startY, eval(width),  val(height)) 
TypeError: __init__() takes from 3 to 5 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

The thing is that my ***main module cannot change***. I have to leave it as it is. It's a requirement. So, how can I solve that problem when I cannot change a thing from it? It only gives me an error on line 18.

main module:

```
import turtle
from chessboard import Chessboard

def main():
    startX, startY = eval(input("Enter a starting point: "))
    width = input("Input a width: ")
    height = input("Input a height: ")

    tr = turtle.Turtle()

    if width == "" and height == "":
        chessboard = Chessboard(tr, startX, startY)
    elif height == "":
        chessboard = Chessboard(tr, startX, startY, width=eval(width))
    elif width == "":
        chessboard = Chessboard(tr, startX, startY, height=eval(height))
    else:
        chessboard = Chessboard(tr, startX, startY, eval(width), eval(height))

        chessboard.draw()

        tr.hideturtle()
        turtle.done()

main()
```

I leave my chessboard.py module in case it has to do something with it:

```
import turtle


class Chessboard:
    def __init__(self, startX, startY, width=250, height=250):
        self.__startX = startX
        self.__startY = startY
        self.__width = width
        self.__height = height

    def draw(self, __startX, __startY, __width=250, __height=250):
        turtle.clear
        self.__drawChessboard(__startX, __startY, __width, __height)

    def __drawChessboard(self, __startX, __startY, __width=250, __height=250):
        # uses height x width, default 250
        turtle.setheading(0)  
        turtle.penup() 
        turtle.goto(__startX, __startY) 
        turtle.pendown() 
        turtle.goto(__startX + __width, __startY)
        turtle.goto(__startX + __width, __startY + __height)
        turtle.goto(__startX, __startY + __height)
        turtle.goto(__startX, __startY)

        self.__drawAllRectangles(self, __startX, __startY, __width, __height)

        turtle.exitonclick()

    def __drawAllRectangles(self, __startX, __startY, __width, __height):
        __checkerWidth = __width / 8
        __checkerHeight = __height / 8
        for row in range(8):
            for column in range(4):
                if row % 2 == 0:
                    self.__drawRectangle(self, __startX + (2 * column * __checkerWidth),
                                         __startY + (row * __checkerHeight), __checkerWidth, __checkerHeight)
                else:
                    self.__drawRectangle(self, __startX + __checkerWidth + (2 * column * __checkerWidth),
                                         __startY + (row * __checkerHeight), __checkerWidth, __checkerHeight)

    def __drawRectangle(self, __startX, __startY, __checkerWidth, __checkerHeight):
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setheading(0)
        turtle.goto(__startX, __startY)
        turtle.fillcolor("black")
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.goto(__startX + __checkerWidth, __startY)
        turtle.goto(__startX + __checkerWidth, __startY + __checkerHeight)
        turtle.goto(__startX, __startY + __checkerHeight)
        turtle.goto(__startX, __startY)
        turtle.end_fill()
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The very first argument the `main` function is passing to your `Chessboard.__init__` is a `turtle.Turtle` object. You are not taking this object into account. You should turn this turtle object into an instance variable of your class, and use it for drawing things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument of every class method, including init, is always a reference to the current instance of the class. By convention, this argument is always named self. In the init method, self refers to the newly created object; in other class methods, it refers to the instance whose method was called.

EDIT: I didnt read the part where you said you can't change the main module, I apologize

```
class Chessboard:
    def __init__(self, tr, startX, startY, width=250, height=250):
        self.tr = tr
        self.__startX = startX
        self.__startY = startY
        self.__width = width
        self.__height = height

    def draw(self):
        self.tr.clear()
        self.__drawChessboard(self.__startX, self.__startY, self.__width, self.__height)

    def __drawChessboard(self, __startX, __startY, __width=250, __height=250):
        # uses height x width, default 250
        self.tr.setheading(0)  
        self.tr.penup() 
        self.tr.goto(__startX, __startY) 
        self.tr.pendown() 
        self.tr.goto(__startX + __width, __startY)
        self.tr.goto(__startX + __width, __startY + __height)
        self.tr.goto(__startX, __startY + __height)
        self.tr.goto(__startX, __startY)

        self.__drawAllRectangles(__startX, __startY, __width, __height)

        self.tr.exitonclick()

    def __drawAllRectangles(self, __startX, __startY, __width, __height):
        __checkerWidth = __width / 8
        __checkerHeight = __height / 8
        for row in range(8):
            for column in range(4):
                if row % 2 == 0:
                    self.__drawRectangle(__startX + (2 * column * __checkerWidth),
                                         __startY + (row * __checkerHeight), __checkerWidth, __checkerHeight)
                else:
                    self.__drawRectangle(__startX + __checkerWidth + (2 * column * __checkerWidth),
                                         __startY + (row * __checkerHeight), __checkerWidth, __checkerHeight)

    def __drawRectangle(self, __startX, __startY, __checkerWidth, __checkerHeight):
        self.tr.penup()
        self.tr.setheading(0)
        self.tr.goto(__startX, __startY)
        self.tr.fillcolor("black")
        self.tr.begin_fill()
        self.tr.pendown()
        self.tr.goto(__startX + __checkerWidth, __startY)
        self.tr.goto(__startX + __checkerWidth, __startY + __checkerHeight)
        self.tr.goto(__startX, __startY + __checkerHeight)
        self.tr.goto(__startX, __startY)
        self.tr.end_fill()
```

Comment: The OP said they are not allowed to change the `main` module

Comment: @Ahmed Tounsi Your code is not working at all. I assume you forgot that it was necessary to add "self" on def __drawRectangle for the self.tr to work, so I changed it and now I get line 20, in main chessboard.draw() TypeError: draw() missing 2 required positional arguments: '_Chessboard__startX' and '_Chessboard__startY'.

Comment: @User3230 Fixed, when I was fixing your code i tried to modify it as little as possible for you to understand where the issue was.
Please take a look at the [Python official documentation for classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).